# CakePHP pagination with HABTM models

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I'm having some problems with creating pagination with a HABTM relationship. First, the tables and relationships:

```
requests (id, to_location_id, from_location_id)
locations (id, name)
items_locations (id, item_id, location_id)
items (id, name)
```

So, a Request has a Location the request is coming *from* and a Location the Request is going *to*. For this question, I'm only concerned about the "to" location.

```
Request --belongsTo--> Location* --hasAndBelongsToMany--> Item

(* as "ToLocation")
```

In my RequestController, I want to paginate all the Items in a Request's ToLocation.

```
// RequestsController
var $paginate = array(
    'Item' => array(
        'limit' => 5,
        'contain' => array(
            "Location"
        )
    )
);

// RequestController::add()
$locationId = 21;
$items = $this->paginate('Item', array(
    "Location.id" => $locationId
));
```

And this is failing, because it is generating this SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM items Item   WHERE Location.id = 21
```

I can't figure out how to make it actually use the "contain" argument of `$paginate`...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to get it working somewhat, but the solution doesn't feel very cakey at all.

```
$items = $this->paginate(
    $this->Request->ToLocation->Item,
    array(
        "Item.id IN ("
        . "SELECT item_id FROM items_locations "
        . "WHERE location_id = " . $locationId
        . ")"
    )
);
```

Comment: This is the only way that worked for me, having non-convention field names in habtm table.

Answer (score 11):

after 3 days searching, I found the way

```
var $paginate = array('Post'=>array('group'=>'Post.id'));
```

It's recomended to add group, because sometimes we will get duplicte posts in different categories

```
$this->Post->bindModel(array('hasOne'=>array('CategoriesPost')), false);
$out = $this->paginate('Post', array('CategoriesPost.category_id'=>array(1,4,7,6)));
```

Add **false** to use bind model to all queries, not only to the following

Comment: Is there a trick to limit the pagination results? I can't seem to get that to work

Answer (score 3):

To paginate HABTM, you need to temporarily bind 'hasOne' join model to model which you paginate:

```
// prepare to paginate Item
$this->Item->bindModel(array('hasOne'=>array('ItemsLocation')));
$contain['ItemsLocation']=array();
$conditions[]=array('ItemsLocation.location_id'=>$locationId);
$order = array('Item.created' => 'desc'); // set order
...
$items = $this->paginate('Item', compact('conditions','contain','order'));
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work. The second parameter of `paginate()` *only* takes conditions. The extra things need to be added to the `$this->paginate` array.

Comment: oh man.. you cant read documentation on pagination? here correct edit from my projects for your case:

$this->paginate['Item']=compact('contain','conditions','order');
$items = $this->paginate('Item');