# Paginate results filtered by condition on associated model (HABTM) using Containable

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, has-and-belongs-to-many, pagination, containable

I need to paginate list of `Product`s belonging to specific `Category` (HABTM association).

In my `Product` model I have

```php
var $actsAs = array('Containable');
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Category' => array(
        'joinTable' => 'products_categories'
    )
);
```

And in `ProductsController`

```php
$this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => 20,
    'order' => array('Product.name' => 'ASC'),
    'contain' => array(
        'Category' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Category.id' => 3
            )
        )
    )
);
$this->set('products', $this->paginate());
```

However, resulting SQL looks like this:

```php
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` 
FROM `products` AS `Product` 
WHERE 1 = 1;

SELECT `Product`.`*` 
FROM `products` AS `Product` 
WHERE 1 = 1 
ORDER BY `Product`.`name` ASC 
LIMIT 20;

SELECT `Category`.`*`, `ProductsCategory`.`category_id`, `ProductsCategory`.`product_id` 
FROM `categories` AS `Category` 
JOIN `products_categories` AS `ProductsCategory` ON (`ProductsCategory`.`product_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20) AND `ProductsCategory`.`category_id` = `Category`.`id`)
WHERE `Category`.`id` = 3
```

(I.e. it selects 20 `Products` and then queries their `Categories`)

while I'd need

```php
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` 
FROM `products` AS `Product` 
JOIN `products_categories` AS `ProductsCategory` ON `ProductsCategory`.`product_id` = `Product`.`id`
JOIN `categories` AS `Category` ON `Category`.`id` = `ProductsCategory`.`category_id`
WHERE `Category`.`id` = 3;

SELECT `Product`.*, `Category`.*
FROM `products` AS `Product` 
JOIN `products_categories` AS `ProductsCategory` ON `ProductsCategory`.`product_id` = `Product`.`id`
JOIN `categories` AS `Category` ON `Category`.`id` = `ProductsCategory`.`category_id`
WHERE `Category`.`id` = 3
ORDER BY `Product`.`name` ASC 
LIMIT 20;
```

(I.e. select top 20 `Products` which belong to `Category` with `id` = 3)

**Note:**
Possible solution without `Containable` would be (as **Dave** suggested) using joins.
[This](http://garbers.co.za/2011/05/03/easy-way-to-generate-cakephp-habtm-joins-for-use-in-pagination/) post offers a very handy helper to build `$this->paginate['joins']` to paginate over HABTM association.

**Note: Still looking for more elegant solution using `Containable` than fake `hasOne` binding.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I found a way to do what I want, so posting it as an answer:

To force `JOIN` (and be able to filter via condition on associated model) in `Containable` - [you've got to use fake `hasOne` association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463296/cakephp-pagination-with-habtm-models/2946029#2946029).

In my case, code in `ProductsController` should be:

```
$this->Product->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('ProductsCategory')), false);

$this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => 20,
    'order' => array('Product.name' => 'ASC'),
    'conditions' => array(
        'ProductsCategory.category_id' => $category
    ),
    'contain' => 'ProductsCategory'
);

$this->set('products', $this->paginate());
```

Note `false` as a second argument to `bindModel` - which makes binding persistent. This is needed because `paginate()` issues `find('count')` before `find('all')`, which would reset temporary binding. So you might want to manually `unbindModel` afterwards.

Also, if your condition includes multiple IDs in HABTM associated model, you might want to add `'group' => 'Product.id'` into your `$this->paginate[]` (as **Aziz** has shown in his answer) to eliminate duplicate entries (will work on MySQL only).

**UPDATE:**
However, this approach has one serious drawback compared to joins approach (suggested by **Dave**): condition can apply only to intermediate model's foreign key (`category_id` in my case); if you want to use condition on any other field in associated model - you'd probably have to add another `bindModel('hasOne')`, binding intermediate model to HABTM associated model.

Answer (score 1):

When you put the condition in the nested Contain, you're asking it to retrieve only the Categories with that ID.  So - it's doing what you're asking, but that's not what you want.

Though it seems like it should be possible, **the only luck I've had doing what you're trying to do** (after MANY hours and a few stackoverflow questions) **is via Joins instead of Contain**.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1047/Joining-tables

It's not the exact same problem, but you can go through some of my code where I query against HABTM conditions (I answered my question at the bottom) here: [Select All Events with Event->Schedule->Date between start and end dates in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373203/select-all-events-with-event-schedule-date-between-start-and-end-dates-in-cakep)

Comment: I tried to move `Category` condition to main `conditions` clause, but it just fails (because it still does not `JOIN` tables but rather does 2 `SELECT`s).

Comment: @Ixa - I don't believe I suggested to do that - unless you've converted the whole thing to join.

Comment: you didn't, I just logically extended your comment _When you put the condition in the nested Contain, you're asking it to retrieve only the Categories with that ID_, - so that moving that condition from nested `Contain` to main `conditions` would impose it to whole query (as it actually did, but it still didn't include the `JOIN`)

Comment: My comment was meant to point out the error in logic of the current code, but it wasn't meant as an answer - My answer was where I specified that I could not get what you were doing to work using Contain - instead, try Joins instead.  Believe me, I'd rather use Contain too - I tried 642 different ways to try to get it to work.  In the end, though, I ended up getting it to work fairly easily with Joins.

Comment: actually I made it work finally using `Containable` - see my own answer

Comment: Gotcha - guess that's where we differed - I needed to run conditions on 5-6+ HABTM tables.  Glad you got it to work the way you were hoping! :)

Comment: `Containable` approach **will** work for many HABTM tables (you just have to add fake `hasOne` binding for each HABTM intermediate table), although only on 1st level on recursion; I'm not sure its possible to make it work for deeper associations (but I didn't check). In any case, `join`s approach is more intuitive (as it corresponds to normal SQL) and allows filtering on fields other than primary key - so it is universal, and probably should be preferred over `Containable`.