# How to connect 3 tables in cakephp? (relations)

Tags: cakephp

I have 3 tables:

```
user:
id;name

usercompany:
id;user_id, company_id

company:
id;company_name
```

How can I connect all 3 tables in cake?
I want to be able to see which companies are connected to the user.
The user can belong to more than one company.

In the user controller I just simply want to use $this->User->find("all") and it should show me all the users with the connected companies (including the company name).

How can I do this in cake? what should I use, hasAndBelongsToMany? Thanks for the insights.

Comment: did you take a look at the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you did not look at the manual, everything you need to know is on [this page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html).

This is a HABTM, hasAndBelongsToMany association. Your join table does not follow the CakePHP convention either, it should be named companies_users. [See the page about conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions). If you don't follow conventions you have to declare everywhere what table, model and foreign keys you're using. If it's a legacy DB and you can't change them, fine. But if it's a new app you should really follow the frameworks conventions, it will make things more easy.

> User <-> CompaniesUser <-> Company

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Company' =>
            array(
                'className' => 'Company',
                'joinTable' => 'companies_users',
                'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
                'associationForeignKey' => 'company_id',
                'with' => 'CompaniesUser'
            )
    );
}
```

You'll have to define the assoc on the "other side", the company model as well.

To be able to fetch all companies for the user in a pagination query you'll have to [define the joins manually](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables). There are plenty of questions and answer on SO that explain how to do this, [here is an one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463296/cakephp-pagination-with-habtm-models), [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655977/cakephp-problem-with-habtm-paginate-query?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps:

Step 1: Create 3 models named User.php, UserCompany.php and Company.php

Step 2: Inside User.php

```
var $hasMany = array(
'UserCompany' => array(
    'className'     => 'UserCompany',
    'foreignKey'    => 'user_id'
)
);
```

Step 3: Inside UserCompany.php

```
   var $hasMany = array(
    'Company' => array(
        'className'     => 'Company',
        'foreignKey'    => 'company_id'
    )
    );
```

Step 4: From controller
    $this->User->find("all")